# ERROR app.use() requires middleware functions: (so how to set router for app.use in express node.js)?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

basically im just trying to seprate routes, models, and controller in node.js application.
i have following files to setup very very basic node.js application.

controller/cv.js

```
module.exports = {

   get: function(req, res, next){
        console.log("GET REQUESTS")
        next();
    }
}
```

routes/cv.js

```
var express = require('express');
var CvRouter = express.Router();
var CvController = require('../controller/cv')


CvRouter.get('/', function(req, res, next){
        console.log("GET REQUESTS")
        next();
    })

module.export = CvRouter
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
var path = require('path')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

 var router = express.Router();
 require('./router')(app)



app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

router.js

```
var CvRouter = require('./routes/cv')


module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use([CvRouter]);
};
```

Basicaly this last file router.js is generting error when i use app.use([CvRouter])
ERROR is:  **throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');**

how i can resolve it? i also know its returning object of router. and app.use expecting function in parameter. but how i can achieve my desired MVC pattern of node.js?

Comment: It might be just a typo when copying, but the second file contains `module.export` instead of  `module.exports`, that makes `CvRouter` undefined...

Comment: Thanks @oshnaps its typo. Please answer it properly so that i can give you points. My problem is resolved.

Comment: Just did so, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as said in comment - you have a typo.
The file `routes/cv.js` contains `module.export` instead of `module.exports`, that makes `CvRouter` undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the array literal

```
var CvRouter = require('./routes/cv')

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(CvRouter);
};
```